# how to track opened push notifications delivered by Amazon SNS

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, analytics, amazon-sns

Hi does amazon SNS support tracking of opened push notifications?

If not, is there a third party analytics service that can track opened notifications in apps (ios android) and combines count of delivered notifications from amazon SNS?

Comment: Wouldn't your app know when a notification was clicked?  It seems like the app could just report that event back to your servers.

Comment: SNS does not support this.  If you're using GCM you can get some visibility into the state of a message from Google, but it's just for debugging.  I believe the best practice is for your app to send a notification back to your back-end that it received the notification.

Comment: Because in parse, with app integration, we can also see app opens. We can do the logging manually but maybe there are existing solutions already

Comment: Hi @Ted - did you find a solution to this? I know there are many third-party services that provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Message delivery can be tracked using Amazon SNS Delivery Status and Amazon CloudWatch:

> You can capture information on success rates, failure rates and dwell times for mobile push notifications using Amazon SNS Delivery Status. These metrics provide insights such as whether your push notifications have been successfully delivered to the intended messaging platform and the time it took for the notifications to be delivered. In addition to collecting status information, you can also trigger alerts based on metrics you define in Amazon CloudWatch.
>
> You can enable this feature by simply selecting to receive “Delivery Status” for your applications in the Amazon SNS console. After this is enabled, the information is captured in an Amazon CloudWatch Logs group that is automatically created by Amazon SNS on your behalf.

See [the initial announcement of this feature.](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/02/05/amazon-sns-adds-delivery-status/)

It’s also described here in this AWS YouTube video:
[How do I confirm delivery of Amazon SNS Push Notifications and find out why some notifications fail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riPEinT9rj4)

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about click through rate, not delivery status.